# cs1503 argument2 cannot convert from 'int' to 'unityengine.scenemanager.loadscenemode'

Tags: c#, unity3d

в Asset store скачал ассет на оружие, дополнил его и добавил SceneManager.LoadScene(), выбивает cs1503 argument2 cannot convert from 'int' to 'unityengine.scenemanager.loadscenemode'. не знаю как фиксить, прошу помощь.
вот скрипт

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class SeryyWeapon : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject GGtext;
    
    public bool canDie = true;                  // Whether or not this health can die

    public float startingHealth = 100.0f;       // The amount of health to start with
    public float maxHealth = 100.0f;            // The maximum amount of health
    private float currentHealth;                // The current ammount of health

    public bool replaceWhenDead = false;        // Whether or not a dead replacement should be instantiated.  (Useful for breaking/shattering/exploding effects)
    public GameObject deadReplacement;          // The prefab to instantiate when this GameObject dies
    public bool makeExplosion = false;          // Whether or not an explosion prefab should be instantiated
    public GameObject explosion;                // The explosion prefab to be instantiated

    public bool isPlayer = false;               // Whether or not this health is the player
    public GameObject deathCam;                 // The camera to activate when the player dies

    private bool dead = false;                  // Used to make sure the Die() function isn't called twice

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start()
    {
        // Initialize the currentHealth variable to the value specified by the user in startingHealth
        currentHealth = startingHealth;
    }

    public void ChangeHealth(float amount)
    {
        // Change the health by the amount specified in the amount variable
        currentHealth += amount;

        // If the health runs out, then Die.
        if (currentHealth <= 0 && !dead && canDie)
            Die();

        // Make sure that the health never exceeds the maximum health
        else if (currentHealth > maxHealth)
            currentHealth = maxHealth;
    }

    public void Die()
    {
        // This GameObject is officially dead.  This is used to make sure the Die() function isn't called again
        dead = true;

        // Make death effects
        if (replaceWhenDead)
            Instantiate(deadReplacement, transform.position, transform.rotation);
        if (makeExplosion)
            Instantiate(explosion, transform.position, transform.rotation);

        if (isPlayer && deathCam != null)
            deathCam.SetActive(true);
            GGtext.SetActive(true);
            Destroy(gameObject);
        SceneManager.LoadScene("lorevidend", 5);
    }
}
```

Comment: `if (isPlayer && deathCam != null)` вот здесь мы же не на питоне пишем, где фигурные скобки? Под условие попадает только первая строка под `if`. Остальные выполняются безусловно. Вы либо скобки расставьте, либо отступы правильно.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SceneManagement.SceneManager.LoadScene.html

Тут сказано что ждет вторым агрументом енамчик SceneManagement.LoadSceneMode

Например

```
SceneManager.LoadScene("SceneName", LoadSceneMode.Additive);
```